# Finding the value of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2(2n+1)}{\exp( \frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2})+\exp ( \frac{3\pi(2n+1)}{2})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, summation, exponential-function

I have a question which askes to find the value of:

$$\displaystyle  \tag*{} \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2(2n+1)}{\exp\left( \dfrac{\pi(2n+1)}{2}\right)+\exp \left( \dfrac{3\pi(2n+1)}{2}\right)}$$

I first changed the sum into:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \lim \limits_{m \to \infty} 2\sum \limits_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{2n+1}{\exp\left( \dfrac{\pi(2n+1)}{2}\right)\left(1+\exp\left(\pi(2n+1)\right)\right)}$

Now, maybe we can change this sum into Integral (Riemann sum to integral) and making it easy to solve? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the question from? For it to be a Riemann sum you would need to find something that is like a $dx$. The uniform spacing partition needs $1/m\sim dx$ for example. Your integrand is independent of $m$ so I kind of doubt this approach

Comment: **Far too naive.** Reduces to evaluation of $\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(2n+1)/\cosh[(2n+1)\pi/2]$. One might try Poisson summation formula, or some heavier stuff (elliptic functions and/or modular forms).

Comment: @metamorphy: I looked some formulas from elliptic function theory and we have a way to deal with sums like $\sum n^k/\cosh(nx) $ for even $k$. For odd $k$ I don't know if a closed form exists.

Comment: Like this question +1